# Is there a way to show which specific fields have been changed on submit in a redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to display a modal that shows which specific fields have been changed in a form when the user presses save (on submit).

I've tried comparing the values and if they are different than the original values, I am printing out the entire object with all the values. However, the only ones I want are the fields that have been changed.

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class SearchFilters extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: ''
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    // check if states are same, if not, setState and doSomething
    const valueString = JSON.stringify(values);
    if ( this.state.values !== valueString ) {
      this.setState({ values: valueString });
      this.props.doSomething(values);
    }
  }

  renderField(field) {
    return (
      <div className="search-parameter">
        <input type="text" {...field.input} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, invalid } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} >
        <Field
          component={this.renderField}
          key="keyword"
          name="keyword"
        />
        <Field
          component={this.renderField}
          key="type"
          name="type"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'SearchFiltersForm',
})(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SearchFilters));
shareeditflag
```

It's pretty much along these lines, I just am lost on how I would pick out the individual fields. I need to save all of the fields, so I'm only trying to DISPLAY the changed ones, so no need to worry about saving only the changed ones.

Comment: I believe there are touched and dirty redux form props. Looks for how to use and access those in the docs

Comment: Try the `getFormMeta` selector: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/selectors.md/

Comment: i'm not really sure how to use dirty, it seems very complex @MiDas

Comment: You can keep doing what u doing and use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff to compare your state with the form values. As an aside i will recommend you use Formik instead of keeping form state globally, it is highly recommended by the react team to keep local, hence formik